# Jest memory leak with apollo server

Tags: node.js, jestjs, apollo-server, ts-jest

We have a memory leak occurring with our apollo server backend tests. I have been trying to find the cause using `jest --detectLeaks` and isolating parts of the app.

If I strip down the app and only run a few tests with our typedefs defined in the same file as our test apollo server, the tests run fine:

```
const typeDefs = {
  ...
}

const resolvers = {
  ...
}

export const testServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: typeDefs,
  resolvers: resolvers,
  ...
});
```

If I move the typedefs to a separate file and import them like we normally do, the memory leak comes back:

```
import { typeDefs } from './typeDefs';

const resolvers = {
  ...
}

export const testServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: typeDefs,
  resolvers: resolvers,
  ...
});
```

So my question is:

Does anyone know what the problem might be and how to fix it?

If not, what is the most likely cause of the issue here? Is it something to do with apollo server? Or is it more likely an issue with jest or a dependency we've included in our project?

Comment: Which version of Apollo Server are you using please?

Comment: @Marcus version 3.3.0 of apollo-server-lambda

Comment: OK, Apollo Server 3 introduced some changes including the need to `await` certain things: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/
However, this does not affect lambda implementations and also I cannot see why importing a file would cause such an issue. Could I ask how you are implementing your typedefs? Is it just as above but in a separate file?

Comment: Yeah just as above but in a separate file. The typedefs are wrapped in a `gql\`...\`` tag.